# Ruby Adapter for Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been struggling with issues(TimeStamp with Timzone, Float values are not parsed correctly) using the ruby-odbc adapter to connect and query Snowflake Warehouse.

Is there a Ruby Adapter other than ruby-odbc(which is not maintained) that I can use to get rid of the issues?

Refer: https://github.com/larskanis/ruby-odbc/issues/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no native Ruby-adapter.

You can use ODBC (as you do) or have a look on the following website that comes to my mind: https://eng.localytics.com/connecting-to-snowflake-with-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 2):

If you're still searching for an adapter, I've worked to create one that works with the Sequel gem, and incorporates some of the parsing fixes found in odbc_adapter, while not being restricted to Rails < 5.2: https://rubygems.org/gems/sequel-snowflake